# Add module documentation to a maven module

Tags: java, maven, module, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I'm trying to add module documentation to maven modules of my project (like I would do in the module-info.java file of my modules). Is there a way to the doc in my module's POM file or to add the module-info file without needing to re-add all the exports?

**In short**, I need to see the "All Modules" view of the generated doc when I run the `mvn javadoc:aggregate` command in my parent project, containing the doc for all of its submodules.

[Example of a javadoc with modules](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html)

Comment: At the moment I see a bug within the maven-javadoc-plugin 3.2.0 - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/MJAVADOC/issues/MJAVADOC-673?filter=allopenissues